# In React what happens if I have a list without key specified to each list item

Tags: reactjs

I know keys are important prop when using array in React. I'm just curious what happens if I don't specify a key for each list item. So I have a very simple case, where I have an array of buttons(react component) in a Dialog component. And those buttons won't change, but Dialog content may change. If I don't specify keys for each button, do my buttons get re-mount every time dialog content changes ?
Is it good practice to ALWAYS include a key, even if it's redundant ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the significance of keys in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801343/what-is-the-significance-of-keys-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 2):

React will default to using the index of an element as a key. If there is a chance that elements can move from their original places, you should set a key to avoid strange behaviour.

React documentation on keys links to this article that describes the bad behaviour.
[Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Main point from that article:

> Let me explain, a key is the only thing React uses to identify DOM
> elements. What happens if you push an item to the list or remove
> something in the middle? If the key is same as before React assumes
> that the DOM element represents the same component as before. But that
> is no longer true.

[React docs about Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

[An excellent video on the subject by Kent C. Dodds](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-the-key-prop-when-rendering-a-list-with-react-b31bfa42)

[Understanding React's key prop, also by Kent C. Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official document's answer to your question! (https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children)